# Using the C preprocessor to generate function declarations

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a lot of functions to declare in this format:

```
int foo_100(int, int);
int foo_200(int, int);
int foo_300(int, int);
int foo_400(int, int);

typedef int (*foo)(int, int);
struct foo foo_library[] = {
    foo_100,
    foo_200,
    foo_300,
    foo_400
};
```

Is there a way I can use the **C** preprocessor to partially automate this task? Ideally, something like this:

foo.txt

```
100
200
300
400
```

foo.h

```
typedef int (*foo)(int, int);

#define DEFINE_FOO(id_) int  foo_##id_(int, int);

DEFINE_FOO(#include"foo.txt")

struct foo foo_library[] = {
    #include "foo.txt"
};
```

Comment: No, the preprocessor can't do something like that. Use a script in some other language to generate the DEFINE_FOO lines.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why this heap of functions ...? What about the bodies ?

Comment: I would personally just write a quick C# app to write my file for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the X macro trick:

```
// foo_list.h
#define MY_FUNCTIONS \
  X(foo_100)
  X(foo_200)
  X(foo_300)
  X(foo_400)
```

Then in your `foo.h` file you define `X` as various macros and invoke `MY_FUNCTIONS`.

```
// foo.h
#include "foo_list.h"

#define X(NAME) \
int NAME(int, int);

MY_FUNCTIONS

#undef X

#define X(NAME) NAME,

typedef int (*foo)(int, int);
struct foo foo_library[] = {
  MY_FUNCTIONS NULL
};

#undef X
```

This is often one of the easiest ways to iterate over a list in the C preprocessor.

Don't remember where I first saw this, maybe it was [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-x-macro/228700289).

Answer (score -2):

С/С++ preprocessor cannot open files and the like.

But you can use scripting engines like php or python to generate files you need.